# Trigger a HTTP request and save the response on MYSQL Result

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, amazon-rds

The program is a Node.js program. The data is stored in MYSQL DB under amazon RDS. It is linked using Sequelize.js. I have some schedule job tasks in the program.
These schedule job follow these step:

1. a select query from database
2. send a request to third party and get the response
3. do something to the response
4. Save log and response to the database

Currently, the schedule jobs is in the Node.js program but when the job start, the Node.js program will become slower.  I am recoding on it and would like to move it to the MySQL server.
I know that the MySQL server have event scheduler but I found that it only can execute some sql code. How can I do some http request? or It is not possible? Any body help?

Comment: So is it the step 1 query tha tis slow? If so show the query and the table structure (`SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}`), and `EXPLAIN {query}`. Moving more code into the least scalable part of your infrastructure isn't a good move. Why haven't you used a message queue for this sort of queue. It has better interface especially as its designed for these sorts of jobs.

Comment: Thanks for @danblack comment. The query is not slow and also there are not much things to step 3. Currently, it is about 2 minutes from step 1 to step 4. The main reason is that the schedule task is frequently, like 5 or 10 minutes. As Node.js is single thread, the program is slower when the task run. Do I change another programming language for the schedule task? any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Keep your Node.js program for processing the requests. Its implemented and does what you don't seem to concerned about its processing time.

I'd move to using a message queue like Rabbit MQ (or AWS queue of some sort) to store the jobs needing to get responses and processed. That way you just push the required things (primary key of the table or identifier) to the queue during your HTTP response, and your Node.js can pick an item off the queue (blocking interface) process it. That way it doesn't need an event based polling to process.

The other advantage to the queue approach is that you can scale up the number of Node.js programs processing these requests without conflicts and you get to maximise the CPU usage without overloading.